# Implementing a delay using timers in STM32

Tags: timer, arm, delay, stm32, cortex-m

Simply, I want to implement a delay function using stm32 timers, like the one in AVR microcontrollers "Normal mode". Can anybody help ? I just can't find that in the stm32 datasheet! It only supports PWM, input capture, output compare and one-pulse mode output!
N.B: I forgot to mention that I'm using stm32F401 microcontroller

Comment: they definitely have timers that you can simply poll or use interrupts like any other mcu.  what specific part are you using, stm32###### look that up on st.com and get the datasheet for pinout stuff and the reference manual or users manual or whatever they call it.  the manual may be generic and describe additional items you dont have, from your part number and the datasheet or manual you can tell what peripherals including timers you have and dont have.

Comment: it all starts with that datasheet.  most of the cortex-ms have a timer in them as well part of the arm logic not the st logic, you can poll or interrupt that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have very special timer for this purpose called SysTick. Set it to overflow every 1ms. In its handler

```
static volatile uint32_t counter;

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    counter++;
}

inline uint32_t __attribute__((always_inline)) GetCounter(void)
{
    return counter;
}

void Dealy(uint32_t ms)
{
  uint32_t tickstart = GetCounter();

  while((GetCounter() - tickstart) < ms);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to delay by periods shorter than milli-seconds 
you can set up a timer to auto-reload and use the internal clock.
The internal clock frequency set to the timer is shown in the cube MX
clock tab. On my NUCLEO-F446RE most timers get 84MHz or 42MHz.

Timer 3 gets 42 MHz by default.
So if I set the pre scaler to 42 and the count period to maximum (0xFFFF
if 16 bit) I will have a cycling clock that changes every micro-second.

I can then, using a property of twos complement maths, simply subtract the 
old time from the new to get the period.

```
void wait_us (int16_t delay) {
    int16_t t1= htim3.Instance->CNT;

    while (( htim3.Instance->CNT - t1 ) < delay) {
        asm ("\t nop"); 
    }
}
```

This is an old trick from PIC18 C coding